# jQuery.after() does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

Please have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/s6VdW/

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
var span1 = $("<span/>").text("Hello");
var br = $("<br/>");
var span2 = $("<span/>").text("World!");
span1.after(br).after(span2);

$("#test").append(span1);
```

Expected result is:

```
Hello
World
```

Expected Result as HTML is:

```
<div>
    <span>Hello</span>
    <br/>
    <span>World</span>
</div>
```

What is the error? According to the jQuery Docs (http://api.jquery.com/after/) it should be possible:

> `.after()` will also work on disconnected DOM nodes.

and

> That set can be further manipulated, even before it is inserted in the document.

**UPDATE**

It seems, that I need to append the first span to the DOM first, before using `.after()`. But what is the alternative? If I can't access the DOM, e.g. because I'm in a DOM-unaware part of the code? http://jsfiddle.net/s6VdW/10/

**UPDATE 2**

I can create a "temporary" div, to which I append the elements to. Then I return the children of that div. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s6VdW/13/ - Does that look like the way to go?

Comment: Please don't *just* post the code in a fiddle. Include the code here and use the fiddle for reference/demo. We like our questions self-contained. =)

Comment: @Sandro, looks like a bug, either in the documentation or in the library. `span1.after(br).after(span2).length` returns `1`, but it should be `3`. Maybe you should open a ticket in [jQuery's bug tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket?redirectedfrom=).

Comment: @Sandro I think you are creating html dynamically so you need to call append() first and then make a call to after().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you create span1 dynamically at the same time you use `.after()` before creating that span element. `span1.after(br).after(span2);` in this line it is gonna search for `span1` element to apply `.after()` but that element is not there. If you understand clearly about why do we have to use `.ready()` it has similarity here. Your code should be like this

```
var span1 = $("<span/>").text("Hello");
var br = $("<br/>");
var span2 = $("<span/>").text("World!");

$("#test").append(span1);
span1.after(span2).after(br);
```

And remember `.after()` add elements from **left to right** so you have to use `.after()` in the order of **9 to 1** so it will give result **1 to 9**.

Hope you got the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating html dynamically so you need to call append() first and then make a call to after().

You should try like

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JS

```
var span1 = $("<span/>").text("Hello");
var br = $("<br/>");
var span2 = $("<span/>").text("World!");
$("#test").append(span1);
span1.after(span2).after(br);
```

order of adding element should be from left to right

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s6VdW/6/)**

Comment: What if I can't access the DOM. E.g. the code is part of a function that dynamically creates these two spans separated by the break and returns it to the caller. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/s6VdW/10/

Comment: In that case you can use append() like return span1.append(br).append(span2);

Comment: No, that produces `<div id="test"><span>Hello<br><span>World!</span></span></div>` http://jsfiddle.net/s6VdW/12/

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one:

```
var span1 = $("<span/>").text("Hello");
var br = $("<br/>");
var span2 = $("<span/>").text("World!");

$("div").append(span1);
span1.after(br);
br.after(span2);
```

do `.after()` when you append first `span1`.

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s6VdW/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var span1 = $("<span/>").text("Hello");
var br = $("<br/>");
var span2 = $("<span/>").text("World!");
span1.after(br);

$("#test").append(span1).append(span2);
```

Comment: This displays the two spans, but I still miss the `<br/>` element. HTML Output: `<div id="test"><span>Hello</span><span>World!</span></div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the after method, you can try something like :

```
// Initialize jQuery objects
var span1 = $("<span/>").text("Hello");
var br = $("<br/>");
var span2 = $("<span/>").text("World!");

// First step : Add the first element to your div
$("div").append(span1);
// Second step : Add the differents elements with the add method (note that I inversed the order to work fine because the after is applied to span1 and not to the last added element.
span1.after(span2).after(br);
```